# Need span to appear in middle of and below another span

Tags: html, css

Trying to do something like this
[image: correctway]

Tried a bunch of different combinations. Can't get it working.

```
    <div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <span>QTY On Order<span>0</span></span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <span>QTY Needed<span>0</span></span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <span>QTY In Stock<span>320</span></span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <span>QTY Consumed<span>20</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phv7mbt3/

Comment: What CSS did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```css
div > div > span {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
div > div > span > span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY On Order<span>0</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY Needed<span>0</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY In Stock<span>320</span></span>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY Consumed<span>20</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you should consider using the `class` attribute to select the elements within css.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly! I will be using a class I just wanted to make it work first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your modified code:

```html
<div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; text-align:center;">
                <span>QTY On Order<span style="display: block">0</span></span>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <span>QTY Needed<span style="display: block">0</span></span>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <span>QTY In Stock<span style="display: block">320</span></span>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <span>QTY Consumed<span style="display: block">20</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

New Code:

```
        <div>
        <div class="qty" style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY On Order</span>
        <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="qty" style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY Needed</span>
        <p>0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="qty" style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY In Stock</span>
        <p>320</p>
        </div>
        <div class="qty" style="display: inline-block">
        <span>QTY Consumed</span>
        <p>20</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.qty{
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phv7mbt3/1/)

You can just replace your `span` with `div`. Also, there should be a slight change in your HTML structure.

To make the text centered, you can just apply a new CSS rule - `text-align:center`.

**Updated HTML**

```
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="text-align:center;">QTY On Order</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">0</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="text-align:center;">QTY Needed</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">0</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="text-align:center;">QTY In Stock</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">320</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <div style="text-align:center;">QTY Consumed</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">20</div>
  </div>
</div>
```